# Possible duplicate question

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Does [What are the pros and cons of joining a Family History Society to advance my research?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/2942/104) overlap enough with [How helpful will joining my local Genealogical Society be if my family research is in a distant location?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/300/104) to be a duplicate?

Edit to add: Raising this here because as a mod I can't simply vote to close.

Comment: Agreed. I have voted to close before seeing this.

Comment: I had searched and the other question had not come up. I have researched using only society and I see it now. I think merging would be suitable to me, as long as the 2 portions of the questions were included. Hope this is where I comment. Could not find anything on the main pages.

Comment: @Very Big Kid, there doesn't seem to be a community consensus to close as a duplicate, and you've accepted an answer. Shall I leave it as it is?

Comment: OK with me either way.